# Detect Chrome Reload mouseclick in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0

I am using Angular2 and want to detect the user has clicked the "reload this page" from the browser.
How can I detect this event in typescript - it is not a keyboard event.

I have tried so far:

```
 @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
 onKeyDown(event: MouseEvent)
 {
    console.log(event);
    alert("keydown "+ event.valueOf());
 }

@HostListener('window:keypress', ['$event'])
onKeyPress(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    alert("keyPress " + event.x);
}

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
public documentClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log(event);
    alert("doc " + event.y);

}
```

But not being hit when user clicks reload from browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  //do something useful here
  return 'oops, user is leaving or reloading the page' //dialog text
};
```

This code will work every time user is trying to leave the page or reload.

FYI:

Also you can listen to 'F5' pressing event and other key combinations, which reload the page. You will need to *preventDefault()* of those events and do some job you need instead. For example this code will prevent refreshing the page via F5 button:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116)
  e.preventDefault();
  //do something useful here
});
```

Comment: Need this in typescript